# Вращающееся меню навигации?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Товарищи, подскажите! Куда копать, возможно ли это вообще - как реализовать такой круг в html, чтобы при клике на конкретное меню - оно вращалось и выбранное меню становилось на верх (как колесо фортуны, но не рандом).

Интересует так же, как это изобразить в коде? Достаточно только css или нужно что-то еще? Есть какие то примеры, наводки?

[image: Вот такой круг нужен, но без стрелок]

**Update:**

Заново прошу помощи! Есть вот такой круг (спасибо MaximLensky): codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dExqLr

Как сделать из него семиугольник (здесь пятиугольник). А так же добавить сверху такие меню, как на картинке?

Как его анимировать, чтобы при нажатии на элемент - круг вращался и наверх по центру становился выбранный элемент, изменялся цвет? Дополнительные меню сверху - просто ссылки, такого же цвета, как и основной элемент.

Важно, чтобы текст и цвета можно было изменить.

Так же прикрепляю примерно что-то похожее (вращение): codepen.io/AndersFly666/pen/GZxVYO

[image: Вот такой круг, только он чб]

Comment: А должно быть визуальное вращение или лишь перемещение местами? Потому что можно сделать статичный такой круг, а при клике просто переопределить цвета рамок и расстановку текстов. А с реальным вращением уже будет "писец как сложно" )

Comment: Со статичным отличная идея, есть пример какой то?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Что касается верстки всяких разных кругов, тут ваши лучшие друзья это 
`Math.sin` `Math.cos` и `Math.PI`

Вот пример с использованием `d3.js`, но могло быть и без него

PS: длинный текст надо тоже вписать в круг и его вращать

Самая актуальная версия тут https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/wbVRGL

```js
let data = Array(5).fill(0).map(object)
let a = Math.PI*2/data.length, start = -Math.PI/2

let r1 = 30, r2 = 35, r3 = 37, r4 = 95;
let basePts = [];
basePts.push(pt(0, r1))
basePts.push(pt(a, r2))
basePts.push(pt(a*2-0.15, r3))
basePts.push(pt(a*1.5-0.1, r4))
let arc = `A ${r4} ${r4} 0 0 1 ${pt(a/2, r4)}` ;

append('path', 'line') 
  .attr('stroke', d => d.color)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('d', 'M' + basePts.join('L') + arc)
  .attr('transform', (d, i) => `rotate(${-i*360/data.length})`)

append('text', 'icon')
  .attr('fill', d => d.color)
  .html(d => d.icon)
  .attr('x', (e, i) => pt(a*i+a*0.7,80)[0])
  .attr('y', (e, i) => pt(a*i+a*0.7,80)[1])

append('text', 'number')
  .attr('fill', d => d.color)
  .html((d, i) => i+1)
  .attr('x', (e, i) => pt(a*i+a*1.5,44)[0])
  .attr('y', (e, i) => pt(a*i+a*1.5,44)[1])

basePts.shift();

append('path', 'active') 
  .attr('d', 'M' + basePts.join('L') + arc)
  .attr('transform', (d, i) => `rotate(${-i*360/data.length})`)
  .on('click', (d,i) => {
    let angle = (i + 1)*360 / data.length
    d3.select('g').attr('transform', `rotate(${angle})`)
    d3.selectAll('text').attr('transform', function(){
        let x = d3.select(this).attr('x')
        let y = d3.select(this).attr('y')
        return `rotate(${-angle},${x},${y})`;
    })
  })  

function append(node, clazz) {
    return d3.select('g')
          .selectAll(node + '.' + clazz)
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append(node)
          .classed(clazz, true)
}

function pt (a, r) {
    a = - a - Math.PI/2
    return [Math.cos(a)*r, Math.sin(a)*r];
}

function object(){
    return {
        color: `hsl(${Math.random()*360},55%,55%)`,
        icon: `&#xf0${Math.floor(Math.random()*100)};`
    }
}
```

```css
text {
    stroke: transparent;
    dominant-baseline: middle;
    text-anchor: middle;
}

.icon {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.number {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 1s;
}

path.active{
    fill: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

g {
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
<svg viewbox="-100 -100 200 200" width="500" height="500">
    <g></g>
</svg>
```

UPD:

Классика жанра, в макете 5 углов, но надо 7, как хорошо что я не умею делать это в `inkscape`, я просто поменяю пару цифр в своем коде

```js
let data = Array(7).fill(0).map(object)
let a = Math.PI*2/data.length, start = -Math.PI/2

let r1=30, r2=35, r3=37, r4=95, rotation=0;
let pts = [];
pts.push(pt(0, r1))
pts.push(pt(a, r2))
pts.push(pt(a*2-0.15, r3))
pts.push(pt(a*1.5-0.45, r4))
let arc = (radius, angle) => `A ${radius} ${radius} 0 0 1 ${pt(angle, radius)}` ;

append('path', 'line') 
  .attr('stroke', d => d.color)
  .attr('d', 'M' + pts.join('L') + arc(r4, a-0.7))
  .attr('transform', (d, i) => `rotate(${-i*360/data.length})`)

append('text', 'icon rotate')
  .attr('fill', d => d.color)
  .html(d => d.icon)
  .attr('x', (e, i) => pt(a*i+a*0.35,80)[0])
  .attr('y', (e, i) => pt(a*i+a*0.35,80)[1])

append('path', 'text-wrap-path')
  .attr('id', (d, i) => `text-wrap-path_${i}`)
  .attr('x', (e, i) => pt(a*i+a*0.77,67)[0])
  .attr('y', (e, i) => pt(a*i+a*0.77,67)[1])
  .attr('d', (e, i) => {
     let c = pt(a*i+a*0.77,67);
     return Array(5).fill(0).map((e,i) => line(Math.acos(1-2/5*i)))
    
     function line(a) {
         let p1 = pt(a, 21), p2 = pt(-a, 21);
         return 'M' + (c[0]+p1[0]) + ',' + (c[1]+p1[1]) + 
                'L' + (c[0]+p2[0]) + ',' + (c[1]+p2[1])
     }
  })

  append('text', 'text') 
      .append('textPath')
      .attr('href', (e,i) => `#text-wrap-path_${i}`)
      .text(d => d.text)
      .attr('fill', d => d.color)
      .attr('startOffset', 40)

append('text', 'number rotate')
  .attr('fill', d => d.color)
  .html((d, i) => i + 1)
  .attr('x', (e, i) => pt(a*i+a*1.2,44)[0])
  .attr('y', (e, i) => pt(a*i+a*1.2,44)[1])

pts.shift();

append('path', 'active') 
  .attr('fill', 'transparent')
  .attr('d', 'M' + pts.join('L') + arc(r4, a-0.7))
  .attr('transform', (d, i) => `rotate(${-i*360/data.length})`)
  .on('click', click)  

lineAndText(r4+15, 0)
lineAndText(r4+30, 1)
lineAndText(r4+45, 2)

function lineAndText(r,n){
    
    append('path', 'line1 l' + n) 
      .attr('id', (d, i) => `line1_l${n}_${i}`)
      .attr('stroke', d => d.color)
      .attr('d', 'M' + pt(a-0.05*(n+1), r) + arc(r, 0.2-0.05*(n+1)))
      .attr('transform', (d, i) => `rotate(${-i*360/data.length})`)

    append('text', 'menu l' + n) 
      .append('textPath')
      .attr('href', (e,i) => `#line1_l${n}_${i}`)
      .text(d => d.menu[n])
      .attr('fill', d => d.color)
      .attr('startOffset', 40)
}

function click(d,i) {
    let angle = (i+1)*360/data.length-30
    let from = rotation;
    rotation = angle;
    
    d3.selectAll('.line1').style('opacity', 0)
    d3.selectAll('.line1.index_'+i).style('opacity', 1)
    
    d3.selectAll('.menu').style('opacity', 0)
    d3.selectAll('.menu.index_'+i).style('opacity', 1)
    
    d3.select('g').transition().duration(1000)
      .attrTween('transform', () => t => `rotate(${from+(angle-from)*t})`)
    
    d3.selectAll('.text-wrap-path').transition().duration(1000)
      .attrTween('transform', function() {
        let x = d3.select(this).attr('x')
        let y = d3.select(this).attr('y')
        return t => `rotate(-${from+(angle-from)*t}, ${x}, ${y})`
    })
    
    d3.selectAll('text.rotate').transition().duration(1000)
      .attrTween('transform', function() {
        let x = d3.select(this).attr('x')
        let y = d3.select(this).attr('y')
        return t => `rotate(-${from+(angle-from)*t}, ${x}, ${y})`
    })
}

function append(node, clazz) {
    return d3.select('g')
          .selectAll(node + '.' + clazz)
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append(node)
          .attr('fill', 'none')
          .attr('class', (d, i) => `${clazz} index_${i}`)
}

function pt (a, r) {
    a = - a - Math.PI/2
    return [Math.cos(a)*r, Math.sin(a)*r];
}

function object(){
    return {
        color: `hsl(${Math.random()*360},55%,55%)`,
        icon: `&#xf0${Math.floor(Math.random()*100)};`,
        menu: [`menu 1`, `menu 2`, `menu 3`],
        text: 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur'.split(' ').filter(() => Math.random() > 0.5).join(' ')
    }
}
```

```css
text {
    stroke: transparent;
    dominant-baseline: middle;
    text-anchor: middle;
}

.icon {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.number {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

path.active{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.line1, .menu {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
text.menu{
    dominant-baseline: text-before-edge;
    font-size:13px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

textPath {
    transition: 500ms;
}

text.menu:hover textPath {
    fill: red;
}
text.text {
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
<svg viewbox="-100 -150 200 300" width="500" height="700">
    <g></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Возможно как то сделать этот вариант, как на моем скрине (обновил вопрос)?

Comment: Круги вокруг - это меню, у каждого элемента (стороны многоугольника) 3 своих меню. И многоугольник на 7 сторон. То есть от каждой стороны идет вверх 3 меню. И получаются визуально 3 круга вокруг

Comment: Точно, а если убрать окружности и сделать прямыми все стороны?

Comment: там на скрине незаметно разделяющей линии. получается 1-й элемент: меню1, меню1, меню1, 2-й элемент: меню2, меню2, меню2. Вращаются вместе со всеми

Comment: Просто супер, а возможно сделать плавную анимацию поворота? И как быть с текстом? Нужны не рандомные иконки и текст) Так же эти верхние меню очень важны. И выбранный элемент подсвечивать.

Comment: О боже, у меня сафари, странно, что в нем не работает! В Гугл хроме все супер!

Comment: Все таки как быть с текстом и меню вокруг? Это посильно вообще?(

Comment: поможете с этим? :'(

Comment: Спасибо, наблюдаю!

Comment: Увидел кроссбраузерность, все работает на сафари!

Comment: Увидел добавленный круг, очень круто!

Comment: А можно сделать как то, чтобы они появлялись при перемещении элемента вверх? Типа будут вот так идти линии только у активного элемента? В целом мне очень нравится то, что выходит.

Comment: @foreigndezigner и пункты меню тоже соответственно?

Comment: Да, имею ввиду целиком нав-итем! Так же что делать с текстом внутри основных элементов, как на макете? И мне нравилось, когда целиком был кликабелен элемент (с иконками).

Comment: @StrangerintheQ текст я так и не дождался ...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вот у меня тупой вопрос ... вот есть тут пользователи с кармой 100 000 и у тебя жирная карма ...скажи на кой чёрт надо это ммм ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я ваще про карму спросил

Comment: @StrangerintheQ даже больше 20 000 их же ни куда не денешь мм , даже пончики не купишь на них

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я знаю - я удалял свой аккаунт , у меня было больше чем у тебя но всё же не ясно для чего эти циферки

Comment: @StrangerintheQ какой рыбий глаз ? дай ссылку

Comment: @StrangerintheQ этот вопрос дубликат так как раньше его уже задавали ...я даже вознагрождение предлагал ...давно это было ..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да я не спорю - тебя тогда не было здесь ... но темя шейдеров вообще интересна ... На youtube Артюх  постоянно их использует но моё мнение что вёрстка должна быть простой и можно было без труда редактировать любую часть кода ..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94691/discussion-between-maximlensky-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 3):

Накидал макет на Svg в редакторе векторной графики Inkscape 
Для этого я вырезал в Gimp нужный фрагмент, и загрузил в inkscape, преимущественно пользовался инструментом path без закрутия пути

Символы добавил с [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.ru/cheatsheet/) что потребовало подключения самого шрифта с cdn и обычное копирование и вставка самой иконки

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 568.39 329.08" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
  <marker id="marker1292" overflow="visible" orient="auto">
   <path transform="matrix(-.8 0 0 -.8 -10 0)" d="m0 0 5-5-17.5 5 17.5 5z" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1pt"/>
  </marker>
  <marker id="Arrow1Lend" overflow="visible" orient="auto">
   <path transform="matrix(-.8 0 0 -.8 -10 0)" d="m0 0 5-5-17.5 5 17.5 5z" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1pt"/>
  </marker>
  <marker id="marker1208" overflow="visible" orient="auto">
   <path transform="matrix(-1.1,0,0,-1.1,-1.1,0)" d="m8.7186 4.0337-10.926-4.0177 10.926-4.0177c-1.7455 2.3721-1.7354 5.6175-6e-7 8.0354z" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".625"/>
  </marker>
  <marker id="marker1174" overflow="visible" orient="auto">
   <path transform="matrix(-1.1,0,0,-1.1,-1.1,0)" d="m8.7186 4.0337-10.926-4.0177 10.926-4.0177c-1.7455 2.3721-1.7354 5.6175-6e-7 8.0354z" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".625"/>
  </marker>
  <marker id="Arrow2Lend" overflow="visible" orient="auto">
   <path transform="matrix(-1.1,0,0,-1.1,-1.1,0)" d="m8.7186 4.0337-10.926-4.0177 10.926-4.0177c-1.7455 2.3721-1.7354 5.6175-6e-7 8.0354z" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".625"/>
  </marker>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(-5 32.083)">
  <g transform="translate(149.58 .86069)">
   <rect x="-144.08" y="-32.444" width="367.39" height="328.08" fill="#fff" stroke="transparent" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="bevel" style="paint-order:stroke markers fill"/>
   <g fill="none" stroke="#000">
    <path d="m35.396 82.306-57.363 41.502 21.142 66.32-89.21-.59735c-17.233-54.667-7.8892-103.2 27.29-145.77" marker-end="url(#Arrow2Lend)"/>
    <path d="m91.741 116.06-56.73-41.022-56.845 40.079-26.902-84.719c53.508-44.43 105.68-33.535 148.52-20.664" marker-end="url(#marker1174)"/>
    <path d="m77.508 181.81 22.118-66.616-57.845-42.758 73.334-52.118c28.655 18.903 70.385 47.877 65.292 136.9" marker-end="url(#marker1208)"/>
    <path d="m10.691 187.15 71.454.39738 21.784-67.126 71.171 52.474c-14.133 60.803-55.838 88.928-108.28 104.32" marker-end="url(#Arrow1Lend)"/>
    <path d="m-13.898 127.55 20.874 66.841 69.305-.31712-27.105 83.665c-83.009.10248-106.6-36.028-132.83-70.543" marker-end="url(#marker1292)"/>
   </g>
   <g fill="#000000" letter-spacing="0px" word-spacing="0px">
    <g font-family="sans-serif" font-size="22.578px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">
     <text x="69.018448" y="80.646423" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="69.018448" y="80.646423" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="22.578px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">1</tspan></text>
     <text x="102.28035" y="156.99762" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="102.28035" y="156.99762" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="22.578px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">2</tspan></text>
     <text x="38.78035" y="224.27737" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="38.78035" y="224.27737" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="22.578px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">3</tspan></text>
     <text x="-35.302982" y="176.65237" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-35.302982" y="176.65237" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="22.578px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">4</tspan></text>
     <text x="-17.916077" y="88.205948" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-17.916077" y="88.205948" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="22.578px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">5</tspan></text>
    </g>
    <g font-family="FontAwesome">
     <text transform="scale(.93541 1.069)" x="66.752991" y="28.498955" font-size="18.708px" stroke-width=".46771" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="66.752991" y="28.498955" stroke-width=".46771"></tspan></text>
     <text transform="scale(.90135 1.1094)" x="-72.378448" y="69.372223" font-size="19.414px" stroke-width=".48534" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-72.378448" y="69.372223" stroke-width=".48534"></tspan></text>
     <text transform="scale(1.0408 .96077)" x="-62.316162" y="224.04454" font-size="22.418px" stroke-width=".56045" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-62.316162" y="224.04454" stroke-width=".56045"></tspan></text>
     <text transform="scale(1.0378 .96357)" x="66.140442" y="267.99738" font-size="20.754px" stroke-width=".51884" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="66.140442" y="267.99738" stroke-width=".51884"> </tspan></text>
     <text transform="scale(.92582 1.0801)" x="160.60985" y="130.09097" font-size="21.602px" stroke-width=".54006" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="160.60985" y="130.09097" stroke-width=".54006"></tspan></text>
    </g>
    <g font-family="'Arial Black'" stroke-width=".26458">
     <text x="-86.254166" y="96.974998" font-size="5.6444px" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-86.254166" y="96.974998">Lorem Ipsum is</tspan><tspan x="-86.254166" y="104.03056">simply dummy </tspan><tspan x="-86.254166" y="111.08611">text of the </tspan><tspan x="-86.254166" y="118.14166">printing and </tspan><tspan x="-86.254166" y="125.19722">typesetting </tspan><tspan x="-86.254166" y="132.25278">industry. Lorem </tspan><tspan x="-86.254166" y="139.30833">Ipsum has been the</tspan><tspan x="-86.254166" y="146.36389">industry's standard</tspan></text>
     <text x="-22.225" y="31.887501" font-size="5.6444px" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-22.225" y="31.887501">Contrary to popular </tspan><tspan x="-22.225" y="38.943058">belief, Lorem Ipsum is </tspan><tspan x="-22.225" y="45.998611">not simply random</tspan></text>
     <g font-size="6.35px">
      <text x="94.720833" y="57.816666" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="94.720833" y="57.816666">t is a long </tspan><tspan x="94.720833" y="65.754166">established fact </tspan><tspan x="94.720833" y="73.691666">that a reader will </tspan><tspan x="94.720833" y="81.629166">be distracted by the</tspan><tspan x="94.720833" y="89.566666"> readable content </tspan><tspan x="94.720833" y="97.530678">(<tspan font-family="Arial">of a page when</tspan>) </tspan></text>
      <text x="93.133331" y="182.17084" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="93.133331" y="182.17084">Contrary to popular</tspan><tspan x="93.133331" y="190.10834">belief, Lorem </tspan><tspan x="93.133331" y="198.04584">Ipsum is not simply</tspan><tspan x="93.133331" y="205.98334">random text.</tspan></text>
      <text x="-31.75" y="218.15417" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-31.75" y="218.15417">Contrary to </tspan><tspan x="-31.75" y="226.09167">popular belief, </tspan><tspan x="-31.75" y="234.02917">Lorem Ipsum is not </tspan><tspan x="-31.75" y="241.96667">simply random text.</tspan></text>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Супер! А возможно 7-и угольник? И разноцветные. Так же убрать стрелки и добавить по 3 ссылки сверху.

Comment: @foreigndezigner  покажите макет ...

Comment: точно такой же многоугольник, но добавить 2 стороны. Их получается нужно просто уменьшить и добавить или как?

Comment: Выше @Stranger дополнил ответ, у него получилось то, что нужно, но без текста

Comment: @foreigndezigner тогда отметьте решением его ответ ...здесь оказывают помощь без платно но за отметку "Решение" и за палец вверх

Comment: @foreigndezigner https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/Ybmbay там текст ссылка - можешь потыкать на все тексты и есть иконка ...